# Occur some event when click on Webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using webview in my application which opens html website. Now as per requirement of my company, I need to occure some event when user click on webview.

I have tried `setOnClickListener()` event but it dint work.

Please guide me for it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a framelayout and then set  webview inside on it, put your onlclick listener on the framelayout